# VBA Outlook does not generate new mailitem from this code

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

When I go to sent emails with the code below it sends a previous version of the email. It doesn't reset.

```
Private Sub CommandButton16_Click()
Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim EmailAddress As String
Dim EmpName As String
Dim ProvName As String
Dim PayMonth As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Filepath As String
Dim FileExists As String
Dim Subject As String
Dim Source As String
Dim AltEmail As String
Dim ExtraMsg As String
Dim i As Long


'Loop through and get email address and names
    i = 2
    PayMonth = TextBox6.Value
    AltEmail = TextBox7.Value
    ExtraMsg = TextBox8.Value
    
Do While Worksheets("Provider Template").Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    ProvName = Worksheets("Provider Template").Cells(i, 1).Value
    EmpName = Worksheets("Provider Template").Cells(i, 11).Value
    If AltEmail = "" Then EmailAddress = Worksheets("Provider Template").Cells(i, 20).Value Else EmailAddress = AltEmail
    Filename = ProvName & " " & PayMonth
    Filepath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Remittance PDFs\"
    Source = Filepath & Filename & ".pdf"
    Subject = "Monthly Remittance Advice for" & " " & ProvName & " - " & PayMonth
    FileExists = Dir(Source)
    If FileExists = "" Then GoTo Lastline Else GoTo SendEmail
SendEmail:
    Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With EmailItem
    EmailItem.To = EmailAddress
    EmailItem.CC = "******************"
    EmailItem.Subject = Subject
    EmailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body><p>Here is the tax invoice and calculation sheet for " & ProvName & ".</p><p>" & ExtraMsg & "</p><p>Kind regards, ******</p><p>****** ******</p><p>Practice Manager</p></body></html>"
    EmailItem.Attachments.Add Source
    EmailItem.Send
    End With
    GoTo Lastline
Lastline:
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

I thought it was a problem in the code then I ran it on a different machine and fresh emails were sent. I uploaded the updated version to a work machine and the old emails are going again, like there is a cache of this stuff somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean with _" previous version of the email"_? Have you executed the code stepwise and checked what or where it is going wrong?

Comment: The emails that are generated are the old ones that I have already created and do not take into account the changes made to the code. (That is, old subject line and content).  I suspect this is a basic error that doesn't result in a new "EmailItem" being generated. On a different machine the newer code generated the correct 22 emails, but this stops at 12, but I think this reflects a previous generation. How do I run this stepwise?

Comment: Stepwise = running your code line-by-line using F8 (or, in the VBE menu, Debug > Step Into) and seeing what the applications (Excel, Outlook) are doing after each line. Reason for doing this is to try and work out which line in the code is not doing what you expect it to do

Comment: The emails were marooned as drafts in the Outlook Outbox. The send command seemed to send a handful at a time, but always old versions. I will test further but email.display is a workaround for now, and I prefer it for the long term. I will edit the rest of the code in the morning and check if send now works without input from the Outlook side now that the Outbox is unclogged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check your "Sent" box in outlook next time. It's possible that outlook did'nt sent them (offline or other reason),thety are still there as a draft. That could be the reason that they where sent later.

And adjust:
`With EmailItem .To = EmailAddress`
And you can leave this out;
`GoTo Lastline Lastline:`